# Dependencies Error

Tags: dependencies, openoffice.org

I recently installed OpenOffice.org because LibreOffice wasn't working. I removed LibreOffice with this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-core
```

And then installed OpenOffice. Now I get an error saying that `BrokenCount >0` and I cannot install / remove anything. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

Open a Terminal and try running apt-get fix

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```